# Do I need a crossdomain.xml file for my MVC2 site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, xss

I am getting the following error in my MVC2 site: The controller for path '/crossdomain.xml' was not found or does not implement IController.

From some research it appears that the file is related to antiforgery and cross site scripting (XSS) attacks. Do I need a crossdomain.xml file for my MVC2 site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do I need a crossdomain.xml file for my MVC2 site?

Only if you want it to be accessible cross domain from client Flash scripts. Also to avoid this error you could exclude it from your routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("crossdomain.xml");
```